# Is there a way to alter CanvasRenderingContext2D.arc so it shows like a pie?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I've been experimenting with the HTML Canvas for weeks, and I use .arc to make circles, but when the circle is incomplete, it doesn't show like a piece of pie. Instead, it uses the shortest distance possible from one end to the other, and it fills the rest! Is there a way for it to show up as pie pieces?
Here's an example using .arc:

```html
<html>
<head>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, 2) //supposedly radians for 2
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fill();
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="600"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Move first to the center of the arc: `ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(100,75);/*Move to the center*/
ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, 2); ctx.closePath();`

Answer (score 0):

So what happens is that `.arc()` literally creates a angled path from your provided x and y coordinates. What you need to do is:

- move your 'drawing pointer' where you want to place the circle
- make a 'path' from that position, which is the center of your circle
- draw the actual pie arc
- go back to your circle to close that path.

The following code illustrates a working example of this:

```js
const WIDTH   = 100;
const HEIGHT  = 100;
const RADIUS  = 50;
const canvas  = document.createElement('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width  = WIDTH;
canvas.height = HEIGHT;

document.body.appendChild(canvas);

//  identify center of your circle for learning purposes
//  let's use the center of the canvas:
const [dx, dy] = [WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2];
context.fillStyle = 'orange';
context.fillRect(dx, dy, 5, 5);

//  clean / begin your paths
context.beginPath();

//  move to (and start your path to) your position:
context.moveTo(dx, dy);

//  create a circle using the dx,dy as the center of the circle:
const startAngleInRadians = 0;
const endAngleInRadians   = Math.PI * 0.5;
const goAntiClockwise     = false;
context.arc(dx, dy, RADIUS, startAngleInRadians, endAngleInRadians, goAntiClockwise);

//  move back to your position (not required if you only draw 1 pie since your paths dont change):
context.moveTo(dx, dy);

//  let's fill our pie with a pink color!:
context.fillStyle = '#FF00FF55';
context.fill();
```

To illustrate what is actually happening I made a simple canvas animation:

```js
const WIDTH   = 200;
const HEIGHT  = 200;
const RADIUS  = 50;
const canvas  = document.createElement('canvas');
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
const [dx, dy] = [0, 0];

canvas.width  = WIDTH;
canvas.height = HEIGHT;

document.body.appendChild(canvas);

context.strokeStyle = 'red';

function sleep(timeout) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(true);
    }, timeout);
  });
}

async function showHowItWorks() {
  //  move from arc center to the arc start position:
  for (let i=0; i<RADIUS; i++) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(dx, dy);
    context.lineTo(dx + i, dy);
    context.stroke();
    await sleep(50);
  }

  //  draw the arc from start position to arc end:
  const angle = Math.PI * 0.5;
  for (let i=0; i<angle; i+=0.05) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(dx, dy, RADIUS, 0, i, false);
    context.stroke();
    await sleep(50);
  }

  //  move from arc end back to the arc center:
  for (let i=50; i>=0; i--) {
    context.moveTo(dx, dy + RADIUS);
    context.lineTo(dx, dy + i);
    context.stroke();
    await sleep(50);
  }
}

showHowItWorks();
```

Of course, there are some flaws: I am not sure whether the `.arc()` command moves the 'drawing pointer' -like `.moveTo()`- or draws from the position to the arc -like `.lineTo()`-.

In the first case, the pointer jumps from your center position to the arc. In the second case it actually creates a line from your center towards the arc. But anyway, both ways will give you the same end result in most cases.